# How do I make a table view always load scrolled to the top?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview, uinavigationbar

I am making an app with 2 table views stacked in a navigation controller, and where the title is a large title. The first table view has many items in it so when you scroll down to get the lower cells, the large title shrinks at the top into a smaller title. However when I then click on one of those lower cells, the new table view starts with the small navigation title at the top, as opposed to starting completely scrolled up with a large title. In order to make the large title reappear in the configuration I want the page to start in, you have to scroll up. How can I make it so each table view starts with a large title, as opposed to matching the title configuration of the table before it?

UPDATE: Here is the code for the first tableview and how I configured the navigation controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        loadCategories()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Advert-Bold", size: setLargeTitleSize())!]
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Advert-Bold", size: setSmallTitleSize())!]
        
        
    }
 
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        
        self.navigationController?.setStatusBar(backgroundColor: UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "darkest")))
        
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "almostWhite"))]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "darkest"))
        
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "darkest"))

        
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - TableView Datasource Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return symptoms?.count ?? 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SymptomCell", for: indexPath)
        
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Advert-Light", size: setTextSize())
        
        //cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "darkest"))
        
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "almostWhite"))
        
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: vc1.defaults.string(forKey: "almostWhite"))
        
        
        
        if let category = symptoms?[indexPath.row] {
            
            cell.textLabel?.text = category.name
        }
        
        
        
        return cell
        
    }
    
    //MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToFlows", sender: self) //performs the segue to the list of items associated with that category.
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destinationVC = segue.destination as! FlowTableViewController
        
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            destinationVC.selectedSymptom = symptoms?[indexPath.row] //this sends the category currently selected over to the selectedCategory variable in the todo list view controller
        }
    }
    
    //MARK: - Data Manipulation Methods
    
    func loadCategories() {
        symptoms = realm.objects(Symptoms.self) //this pulls out all the items with type category, and adds them all to the array of categories.
        
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Hi Julian, you need to show your current code so we can help you.

Comment: Sorry about that, new to stack overflow. Here you go.

Comment: Let me know if you need more code than that.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `prefersLargeTiles`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```

Then setting `largeTitleDisplayMode` if it's still not doing what you need

```
navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

Comment: That is exactly what I figured would work but I tried setting it as always in both the code and the storyboard along with the prefersLargeTitles property set to true, and neither worked.